# Map function with evaluated and unevaluated parameters

Tags: evaluation, map, hold

Let's consider a function with evaluated and unevaluated arguments inside:

```
list1 = {1,2,3}
list2 = {x,y,z}

fun[list_]:={list,ToString@Unevaluated@list}
```

When I use Map over `fun` I expect to get result like this:

```
{fun[list1],fun[list2]}
(*{{{1, 2, 3}, "list1"}, {{x, y, z}, "list2"}}*)
```

But instead I get this:

```
fun /@ {list1, list2}
{{{1, 2, 3}, "{1, 2, 3}"}, {{x, y, z}, "{x, y, z}"}}
```

This is surely connected with my misunderstanding of evaluation behaviour, but no obvious answer was found in Robby Villegas notebook https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/ , nor here in StackExchange. How to solve this problem?

ver. 12.1, Windows 10

**EDIT**
Setting attribute `Listable` help a bit making unnecessary to use `Map`:

```
SetAttributes[fun, {HoldAll, Listable}];
fun[{list1,list2}]
``
(*{{{1, 2, 3}, "list1"}, {{x, y, z}, "list2"}} *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the Map command which needs to use `HoldAll`. This is one way to make it work. There might be other ways

```
SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[Map, HoldAll]
fun[list_] := {ToString@HoldForm@list, list}
list1 = {1, 2, 3}
list2 = {x, y, z}
fun /@ {list1, list2}
```

[image]

If you do not add `SetAttributes[Map, HoldAll]` then this is what you get

[image]

This shows that `Map` is the one which evaluated its argument, so too late by the time it reaches your function.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer.

Answer (score 7):

The keypoint is, if a function doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute, its argument(s) will always be evaluated before going **into** the function. So in your case, you need to stop the automatic evaluation 3 times. One for `Map` (`/@`), one for `fun` and one for `ToString`. You've already properly handled `ToString` with an `Unevaluated` and `fun` with the `HoldAll` attribute. For `Map`, you just need one more `Unevaluated`:

```
list1 = {1,2,3};
list2 = {x,y,z};

SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll]
fun[list_]:={list,ToString@Unevaluated@list}
fun /@ Unevaluated@{list1, list2}
```

Setting `HoldAll` attribute on `Map` as shown in Nasser's answer is another way to go, but generally it's not a good idea to modify built-in functions. BTW, if you don't want to set `HoldAll` on `fun`, you can introduce a pure function as the wrapper as follows:

```
ClearAttributes[fun, HoldAll]

Function[a, fun@Unevaluated[a], HoldAll] /@ Unevaluated@{list1, list2}
```

Notice the `HoldAll` inside `Function` stops the automatic evaluation of argument of pure function, and the `Unevaluated` inside `Function` stops the automatic evaluation of argument of `fun`.

Comment: very simple and clear explanation, thanks for Your help!