# HoldForm not working with Map

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, expression-manipulation, hold

I am debugging a `ListPlot` implementation and I need to see the command. To avoid huge list of numbers, i just need the `ListPlot` like command to return the name of variables it is going to plot. My idea is to do something like `HoldForm` but it seems that `HoldForm` does not work with `Map` if the variable is a list. E.g.

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
g = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}};
MapThread[q[HoldForm@#1, #2] &, {{f, g}, {a, b}}]
```

returns

```
{q[{{1,1},{2,2}},a],q[{{3,4},{5,6}},b]}
```

Obviously, I want:

```
{q[{f,a],q[g,b]}
```

After trial and error I found this to work:

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
g = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}};
MapThread[
 q[HoldForm@#1, #2] &, {{Unevaluated@f, Unevaluated@g}, {a, b}}]
```

But it is way too cumbersome, I really do not want to put `Unevaluated` in front of each list.

Surprisingly, this does not work

```
MapThread[q[HoldForm@#1, #2] &, {Map[Unevaluated, {f, g}], {a, b}}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to put `Unevaluated` in front of each data list, or even better just keep some kind of `Hold` in the function (or first argument of `MapThread`? Or is this unachievable as the `f` and `g` are expanded before getting to the slot? In that case why I cannot map `Unevaluated` as in the last example?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279842/1871

Answer (score 7):

Another question about evaluation control. The keypoint is, if a function doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute, its argument(s) will always be evaluated before going **into** the function. So in your case, you need to stop the automatic evaluation 3 times. One for `q`, you've already done it with `HoldForm`, but I prefer a `Hold*` attribute; one for 2nd argument of `MapThread`, you only need one `Unevaluated`; one for `&`, this is easy to ignore, but don't forget its `FullForm` is `Function`, so automatic evaluation happens when arguments pass through it! To sum up, the following is a possible solution:

```
f = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
g = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}};
SetAttributes[q, HoldFirst];
MapThread[Function[{arg1, arg2}, q[arg1, arg2], HoldFirst], 
          Unevaluated@{{f, g}, {a, b}}]
```

Your last sample doesn't work because you've forgotten `Map` doesn't have `Hold*` attribute, either. To fix it, you need to stop the automatic evaluation of 2nd argument of `Map`. The following is a possible solution:

```
ClearAll@q
MapThread[q[HoldForm@#1, #2] &, {Map[Unevaluated, Unevaluated@{f, g}], {a, b}}]
```

As to `Unevaluated`, it is a special function, it owns some properties that cannot be explained in usual way. I'd recommend reading this:

https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377

Some other posts showing its special behavior:

[Why one needs two Unevaluated to show 1+1 correctly in TreeForm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110490/1871)

[Why Unevaluated doesn't work on unheld side of Rule/RuleDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110499/1871)

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem with the pre-existing definitions for `f` and `g`.  You can temporarily over-ride these, using `Block`

```
Block[{f, g}, MapThread[q[HoldForm@#1, #2] &, {{f, g}, {a, b}}]]
(* {q[f,a],q[g,b]} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make an auxiliary function which maps `HoldForm` over all elements of the list.

```
SetAttributes[holdList, HoldAll];
holdList[lst_] := ReleaseHold@Map[HoldForm, Hold@lst, {-1}]

MapThread[q[#1, #2] &, holdList@{{f, g}, {a, b}}]
(* {q[f, a], q[g, b]} *)
```